# Where gdi objects are kept?

Tags: windows, winapi, gdi

Are gdi objects, acquired by an application, stored in the 2GB virtual memory space reserved for the Windows kernel, in the app virtual memory space ?

If so, could you please provide related links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're stored in the kernel, see [Mark Roussinovich's blog entry on USER and GDI objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/markrussinovich/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-user-and-gdi-objects-part-1).

Comment: Do you know what a session pool is ? `"Unlike USER objects, GDI objects aren’t allocated from desktop heaps; instead, on Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 systems that don’t have Terminal Services installed, they allocate from general paged pool; on all other systems they allocate from per-session session pool"`

Comment: A paged pool in kernel dedicated solely to session-related data.

Comment: Ok, but how does it differ from a general paged pool ?

Comment: Never mind. I found a very good link about this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2007/01/04/desktop-heap-overview.aspx

Comment: Both of these links are now stale.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Updated link in answer. The other is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ntdebugging/desktop-heap-overview .